# Deserialize two different JSON representations into one object

Tags: java, spring, jackson, lombok

I have Java class like

```java
@Data
public class Comment  {
  private Integer id; // should be used anyhow
  private Long refId; // for internal purpose -> not be serialized
  private String text; // should be used in QuickComment 
  private String patch; // should be included in PatchComment ONLY
  private String status; // should be included in StatusComment ONLY
}
```

and I have

```java
@Data
public class Response{
  private Comment statusComment;
  private Comment patchComment;
}
```

I thought about using `JsonView` like

```java
public class Views{
  public interface StatusComment{}
  public interface PatchComment{}
}
```

and apply them to the inital class

```java
@Data
public class Comment  {
  @JsonView({Views.StatusComment.class, Views.PatchComment.class})
  private Integer id; // should be used anyhow
  private Long refId; // for internal purpose -> not be serialized
  @JsonView({Views.StatusComment.class, Views.PatchComment.class})
  private String text; // should be used anyhow
  @JsonView(Views.PatchComment.class)
  private String patch; // should be included in PatchComment ONLY
  @JsonView(Views.StatusComment.class)
  private String status; // should be included in StatusComment ONLY
}
```

and the `Response`

```java
@Data
public class Response{
  @JsonView(Views.StatusComment.class)
  private Comment statusComment;
  @JsonView(Views.PatchComment.class)
  private Comment patchComment;
}
```

But somehow it fails completely. It fails completly, ie. nothing is filtered. Is it problem with Lombok. Or is it defined incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you serialize your objects? Are you using Spring? Are you using the `ObjectMapper` directly?

If you're using Spring then what you need to do is annotate method of your controllers with `@JsonView(Views.StatusComment.class)` or `@JsonView(Views.PatchComment.class)` like:

For reading `GET` endpoints

```java
@JsonView(Views.StatusComment.class)
@RequestMapping("/comments/{id}")
public Comment getStatusComments(@PathVariable int id) {
    return statusService.getStatuscommentById(id);
}
```

For writing:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Comment saveStatusComment(@JsonView(View.StatusComment.class) @RequestBody Comment c) {
    return statusService.saveStatusComment(c);
}
```

If you're using the `ObjectMapper` directly, then what you need to do is specify the used `View`:

When writing:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String result = mapper
    .writerWithView(Views.StatusComment.class)
    .writeValueAsString(comment);
```

When reading:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Comment comment = mapper
    .readerWithView(Views.StatusComment.class)
    .forType(Comment.class)
    .readValue(json);
```

Comment: ahhhh... but this would mean that I don't get an object which contains both entries at the same time? e.g. `return Response`. The entries differ in content.

Comment: The `Views` are used so that you can use the same object in different contexts. For example you have a public version of an object and and a one just for your own eyes. Then you can use just one class, but depending on which View is used, you'll see different content.

Comment: ahhh.... I see... and how to get for the same object two different versions of the content? (using Spring)

Comment: I have added an example